# Is there a configuration file for Photos?

Tags: release-loki, settings, photos

Is there a configuration file for Photos, .ini or something else, to fiddle around with advanced settings? Or some other way to do that.

Comment: If it helps at all, Photos is based on Shotwell, and more information about it (including source) can be found here: https://launchpad.net/pantheon-photos - I'll try find out where the config files live, but this information might well help you find it yourself. Looks like ```~/.local/share/pantheon-photos``` contains what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The stuff you're looking for would appear to live in...

`~/.local/share/pantheon-photos`

This directory contains a data directory, which contains 2 database files. Those 2 files appear to be in SQLite format, and you should be able to open and edit them using an SQLite browser such as [GUI Editor for SQLite Databases](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sqlitebrowser/)

Naturally the .bak file seems to be a backup of the other file. I'm not sure why, but presumably in the event that the photos app crashes, it will resort to using the backup. I would recommend having Photos closed when making changes to the database files. Be aware that any changes you make in the Photos app may also be overwritten if you make changes in the database browser afterwards. Just, generally speaking, don't have the database file and Photos app open at the same time.

Further background information: Elementary OS seems to use their own take on Shotwell photo viewer, and as such the configuration files live in the same place. This appears to be true of some other Elementary apps.

Comment: I'm affraid it's only the database with the images imported from the Pictures folder in Home, or whichever is set. When there are no imported images in Photos, the folder `~/.local/share/pantheon-photos` is empty.

Comment: What sort of configuration are you looking for specifically? I'll take a look and see if I can find it elsewhere...

Comment: An .ini file, for example. Like the one xnview uses and it can be found in `~/.config/xnviewmp/`

Comment: I'll be looking through code to see what it will be writing, so an example of a setting would be really useful, e.g to know that you are looking specifically for settings about your preferred view mode (list vs tiles) or similar? I don't use the app so don't actually know any settings that are available, otherwise I'd look for one I know of.

Comment: For example, I was interested to see if I can change the way Photos handles camera raw files. If I shoot b&w in camera, the picture is viewed in color in Photos. Also, if there are lots of large camera raw files in a folder, Photos (Photo Viewer actually) takes some time to load them all and only then I can browse through them with the arrow buttons. In xnview I can deal with problems like this and the .ini file helps.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look and let you know if I find anything probably later on today. I would expect these settings to be specified in the db file since they seem to be per-image, but never say never :)